# How to set NSPredicate to return dates on local time zone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a predicate that return events of a selected day but it returns a date with different time zone. how make the predicate to search for dates according to the local time zone?

```
NSTimeInterval time = floor([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] / 86400.0) * 86400.0;
NSDate *start = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:time];

NSTimeInterval secondsInTwentyFourHours = (24 * 60 * 60);
NSDate *end = [start dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInTwentyFourHours];

// Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:start endDate:end calendars:nil];
// Fetch all events that match the predicate
events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```